# Deploy a docker image from a registry with basic auth

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I've been trying to push a docker image from a private registry to Swisscom Cloudfoundry. The registry is protected by basic auth since we do not want to provide access to anyone.

Now, using the cf CLI, I would like to push the image to cloudfoundry:

```
cf push appname -o my-registry.domain.com/image
```

Logically this will result in an error which states that no authentication credentials are provided.

```
cf push appname -o username:password@my-registry.domain.com/image
```

results in an unspecified error during staging.

Is there any way to push an image from a registry which is protected by Basic Auth via CF CLI?

I was not able to find anything in the CF CLI documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cf push` currently (version 6.26.0) does not support private docker registries.
This feature is currently being added to the Cloud Controller. It is not even available yet in the latest CF release (v258) but the API is documented in the CC release candidate documentation: http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/release-candidate/apps/creating_a_docker_app.html
You can use `cf curl` to call this API until `cf push` supports it.
The CLI tracker story to follow is https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/143540893.

Comment: I just wanted to add something: This feature will very likely be implemented soon, as it is already in the 1.28.0 release of capi: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-release/releases/tag/1.28.0

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry will support pushing apps from images in private Docker repositories pretty soon, the feature has been released as part of Cloud Controller [CC 1.28.0](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-release/releases/tag/1.28.0). Expect this feature to be released in [CF v260](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/releases/), which should be adopted by providers within the next 4 to 6 weeks.

The Command Line Interface (CLI) has a story in their backlog to support adding username/password as parameter and environment variable to `cf push`.